# Assigning vector values to segments in numpy

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to segment the vector `y` using edges in `cutoffs` using numpy (and only numpy). `y` and `g` are defined as column vectors, but `a` is returned as row vector. Running `g += a.transpose()` generates a shape-conformity error (copied below) by introducing a 100x100 array. There has to be a more elegant way to get this done. Thanks.

```
 y = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
 cutoffs = np.random.uniform(0,1,3)
 cutoffs.sort()
 g = np.zeros( y.size )
 for c in np.hstack( [ cutoffs , 1. ] ):
     a = np.array( [ y < c ] )
     g += a.transpose()


 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
 ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (100,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (100,100)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? ... regarding the error you need to modify the code as below ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The objective is to assign segments to `y`, then `map` a function to each of these segments, similar to `tapply()` in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
a = (y < c).reshape(-1)
g += a
```